# Jquery, show large picture on click of smaller image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm using 2 of these: https://0.s3.envato.com/files/74303492/index.html scroller scripts on a website. This looks as follows:

http://www.thinktwice.nl/slider.jpg

If you move the mouse over the small thumbnails or on the large picture the visitor will see a left and right arrow to scroll trough the pictures.

I want to achieve that when you click on a thumbnail, that it is showed in the large picture area.

The large pictures are shown like this:

```
<ul class="ts-list">
<li data-src='images/thumbnails/website/350930_1e.jpg' id='mainImage'><img src='images/placeholder.png'></li>
<li data-src='images/thumbnails/website/350930_2e.jpg' id='mainImage'><img src='images/placeholder.png'></li>
<li data-src='images/thumbnails/website/350930_3e.jpg' id='mainImage'><img src='images/placeholder.png'></li>
<li data-src='images/thumbnails/website/350930_4e.jpg' id='mainImage'><img src='images/placeholder.png'></li>
<li data-src='images/thumbnails/website/350930_5e.jpg' id='mainImage'><img src='images/placeholder.png'></li>
</ul>
```

The small pictures are shown as follow:

```
<ul class="ts-list">                                                
<li style='cursor:pointer;' data-src='images/thumbnails/website/350930_1a.jpg'><img src='images/placeholder.png'></li>
<li style='cursor:pointer;' data-src='images/thumbnails/website/350930_2a.jpg'><img src='images/placeholder.png'></li>
<li style='cursor:pointer;' data-src='images/thumbnails/website/350930_3a.jpg'><img src='images/placeholder.png'></li>
<li style='cursor:pointer;' data-src='images/thumbnails/website/350930_4a.jpg'><img src='images/placeholder.png'></li>
<li style='cursor:pointer;' data-src='images/thumbnails/website/350930_5a.jpg'><img src='images/placeholder.png'></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see the source of the image is in the list element and is called "data-src".

The script requires to do it this way if you want to use the lazy loading feature. I can easily use a javascript that changes the "src" of the big picture when clicked on the small thumbnail. But with the data-src I just can't get it to work. Any idea's? Can it be done?

**EDIT:**

If i show the pictures by the normal image tag then the following code works:

Large pictures:

```
<ul class="ts-list">
<li><img id='mainImage' src='images/thumbnails/website/350930_1e.jpg'></li>
<li><img id='mainImage' src='images/thumbnails/website/350930_2e.jpg'></li>
<li><img id='mainImage' src='images/thumbnails/website/350930_3e.jpg'></li>
<li><img id='mainImage' src='images/thumbnails/website/350930_4e.jpg'></li>
<li><img id='mainImage' src='images/thumbnails/website/350930_5e.jpg'></li>
</ul>
```

Small pictures:

```
<ul class="ts-list">                                                
<li style='cursor:pointer;' data-src='images/thumbnails/website/350930_1a.jpg' onclick="showImage('images/thumbnails/website/350930_1e.jpg')"><img src='images/placeholder.png'></li>
<li style='cursor:pointer;' data-src='images/thumbnails/website/350930_2a.jpg' onclick="showImage('images/thumbnails/website/350930_2e.jpg')"><img src='images/placeholder.png'></li>
<li style='cursor:pointer;' data-src='images/thumbnails/website/350930_3a.jpg' onclick="showImage('images/thumbnails/website/350930_3e.jpg')"><img src='images/placeholder.png'></li>
<li style='cursor:pointer;' data-src='images/thumbnails/website/350930_4a.jpg' onclick="showImage('images/thumbnails/website/350930_4e.jpg')"><img src='images/placeholder.png'></li>
<li style='cursor:pointer;' data-src='images/thumbnails/website/350930_5a.jpg' onclick="showImage('images/thumbnails/website/350930_5e.jpg')"><img src='images/placeholder.png'></li>
</ul>
```

And the working javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
        function showImage(image){          
            var mainImage = document.getElementById('mainImage');                    
            mainImage.src = image;
        }
</script>
```

But as I said I need it to load in the lazy way, because there are about 40+ 800x600px images loading.

Comment: `$(your-selector).data('src')` will return the `data-src`.

Comment: It can definitely be done. Why don't you put up the JavaScript you've attempted to use so far, and we can provide feedback on how to get it working like you want it to?

Comment: You can have only one big image and change its source based on the clicked thumbnail.

Comment: I edited the post with code that works if not using data-src for the source of the image.

Comment: Anyone willing to help me with this?